# Google-chrome tab fonts in Kubuntu look ugly, how to fix this?

Tags: kubuntu, fonts

This is a recurring problem with Kubuntu for me. When I install it on top of a Ubuntu installation (packages `kubuntu-desktop` or `kubuntu-full`), I get ugly fonts.

Does anyone know how to fix the fonts for the tabs of google chrome?

[image: screenshot]

In Ubuntu they are very sharp:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have not installed Kubuntu on top of Ubuntu. The fonts used to be nice until a recent update (first in Google Chrome then in Chromium as well). Thus, I believe this is Chrome's own problem. I wonder if anybody knows how to solve it.

Comment: @DanielTkatch The solution that I applied (self-answer below) worked quite well for me. It improved Chrome tabs (I admit that in Ubuntu they still look smoother, but this result is now acceptable). However, system-wide the fonts are much more enjoyable now!

Answer (score 3):

System Settings > Appearance > Fonts

Enable anti-aliasing

[image]

Use subpixel rendering with "Slight" Hinting.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings -> Application Style -> GNOME/GTK Application Style -> Font

Select a different font from the list. Restart Google Hhrome and you'll notice the changes applied.